# syntax error when using gdal in python console QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, rasterization

When I run the following code in the python console in QGIS I get a syntax error:

```
import osgeo.gdal
gdal_rasterize [-b 1] [-burn 255] [-a Pixelkost] [-te 170000.2 168000.27 177999.8 177999.8] <Adp322.shp> <work.tif>
```

b command for burning it in band number 1
burn command for the color red
a command for using the attribute pixelkost
te command for x,y min and x,y max
the already loaded Adp322.shp file (I also tried it with the whole system path towards the file but this didn't work either)
work.tif is the name the new file should have. (Should this maybe be an already existing file? but how should I produce this?)

Comment: Have you tried without the brackets? See http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html, the examples at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, tried it without too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdal_rasterize is not a python module, but an exe file. You can not call it that easy inside the python console.

See this blogpost on how to wrap the operating system around it:

http://geoinformaticstutorial.blogspot.de/2012/11/convert-shapefile-to-raster-with-gdal.html

```
import os
os.system('gdal_rasterize -a ICE_TYPE -where \"ICE_TYPE=\'Open Water\'\" -burn 2 -l ' + shapefileshortname +' -tr 1000 -1000 ' +  shapefile + ' ' + outraster
```

Comment: But I am trying to do this straight in the command line from the console in QGIS...

Your document is telling me to do this: Using gdal_rasterize is described here and from command line I would call for one of the polygons:         gdal_rasterize -a ICE_TYPE -where "ICE_TYPE='Open Water'" -burn 2 -l ice20120608_3575 -tr 1000 -1000 C:\...\ice20120608_3575.shp  C:\...\ice20120608_3575.tif  
       
What I am already doing.

Comment: Command line is the DOS box called `OSGEO4W Shell` on Windows, or Terminal on Linux. That is not the python console.

Comment: or Mac OS X ...(Terminal)

Comment: Still not working. When I run the following code in python console after 'import os', I just get the value '32512' as a result...



os.system('gdal_rasterize -b 1 -a Pixelkost -burn 255 -te 170000.2 168000.27 177999.8 177999.8 /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/GRBgis_322/Shapefile/Adp322.shp /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/Test.tif')

Comment: when I type the command as in the link, in the terminal: mbp-van-peter:~ PeterVanvoorden$ gdal_rasterize -b 1 -a Pixelkost -burn 255 -te 170000.2 168000.27 177999.8 177999.8 /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/GRBgis_322/Shapefile/Adp322.shp /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/test.tif ....... I get: -bash: gdal_rasterize: command not found ........ maybe there is something wrong with my gdal installation?

Comment: If `gdalinfo --version` does not work, yes. What repository did you use, on which OS? I use ubuntugis unstable (not yet for Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I am working with Mac OSX Version 10.9.2
I have no idea which repository, where can I find it?

Comment: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete. But I can not help you further with Mac issues.