# Converting hundreds of georeferenced JPG files to GeoTIFF using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, geotiff-tiff, world-file

I've to convert hundreds of georeferenced JPEG files (.jpg + .jpw) in the GeoTIFF (.tif) format. The coordinates of the world file (.jpw) should not get lost and the file size should not increase. Is there a way to do this as a batch process in QGIS?

**EDIT:**

Based on Steven's answer I've created a for loop that can be used in th QGIS Python console (Ubuntu):

```
import os
os.system("""
for f in /home/user/*.jpg;
    do gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -a_srs EPSG:3857 $f ${f%.*}.tif
done
""")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably easiest to do using **gdal_translate**. I'm sure it can also be done within QGIS itself, I'm just more used to using the command line :)

Let's break it down to converting one file.

I downloaded [the first map from here](http://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/resources_maps.html) for an example, a georeferenced antiquarian map of Edinburgh in georeferenced JPEG format.

It doesn't appear to have a CRS attached, but no problem... we can set this with QGIS. I also had to add a NODATA value of 0 in the transparency tab to get rid of the black border...

[image]

The following is a suggestion - check out the [manual page](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) as there may be other settings you'll need in your case.

It's possible to apply JPEG compression to a TIFF to keep the file size down. This only makes sense for scanned maps and aerial imagery, though.

In my case the file is 74400010.jpg, so I gave the same name to the tiff

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR 74400010.jpg 74400010.tiff
```

You should now have a geoTIFF. This stores the metadata (equivalent to the jpw world file) in the tiff file itself. 
Looking at the two versions side-by-side, I see no quality degradation:-

[image]

In my exampe the JPEG was 7.1Mb in size, the TIFF slightly bigger (11 Mb). Without applying JPEG compression the tiff is 133Mb, more than 10 times bigger.

I used a fairly conservative quality setting, you can reduce that value or leave it out (default is 75). Only your eyes will tell you where the quality/file size trade-off is right. With my example map, I could get a TIFF that was smaller than the original JPEG, but still acceptable quality.

If you're planning to serve these over a web service like WMS/WMTS, you should look into using the various tiling options, and consider using **gdaladdo** to add overviews (pyramids).

I'm sorry that doesn't answer the 'how to batch process' question, but I'm not sure whether you're using Windows/Mac/Linux. But it would be fairly easy to script this in Python or with a shell script (or whatever the Windows equivalent is these days!)

Comment: @ Steven Kay, `gdal_translate` works fine, but I've to set the CRS manually (`-a_srs EPSG:3857`).  As far as I know, world files do not contain any information about the CRS.

Comment: Is it possible to use `gdal_translate` for directories instead of files? Wildcards (*) work for the input directory (`/home/input/*.jpg`) but not for the output directory.

Comment: It seems that running `gdal_translate` through the Python console in QGIS is quite simple:
`import os
os.system('gdal_translate ...')` See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/syntax-error-when-using-gdal-in-python-console-qgis

Comment: How to batch process: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101800/how-to-translate-tens-of-images-from-a-directory-as-a-batch-with-gdal-translate

Answer (score 0):

This question may be useful: [How can I transform a georeferenced JPG to a georeferenced TIF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-can-i-transform-a-georeferenced-jpg-to-a-georeferenced-tif).  The second answer shows an example using QGIS.  Since you have 100s of files to convert, you will need to script this.  You will need to get a list of all the files in your folder that need to be converted, loop thru each and convert.  Here is the [Translate documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html).